# Boot loader fails to install fatal error

Tags: boot, system-installation, bootloader

Burnt a disc image with lubuntu 17.10.
Last step of installing it says grub boot loader failed to install fatal error.

I know nothing about computers...

Erase disc install,on hp 2530p

Can someone provide easy fix?

Link to message
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYiSD.jpg

THANK YOU!

Comment: HP EliteBook 2530p - 12.1" - Core 2 Duo SL9400 - Vista Business - 4 GB RAM - 80 GB SSD Series

PROCESSOR / CHIPSET

CPU

Intel Core 2 Duo SL9400 / 1.86 GHz

Number of Cores

Dual-Core

Cache

L2 - 6 MB

64-bit Computing

Yes

Data Bus Speed

1066 MHz

Chipset Type

Mobile Intel GS45 Express

CACHE MEMORY

Type

L2 cache

Installed Size

6 MB

RAM

Configuration Features

1 x 2 GB

Technology

DDR2 SDRAM

Installed Size

4 gb

Comment: Hi, I reinstalled win 10 (with new partitions), and added lubuntu alongside. I changed the size of lubuntu and win spaces (was that repartitioning?), But same error message.. maybe liveusb is something I miss? Will Google it.

Comment: Googled.. is there a difference using USB or DVD to install?

Comment: Only tried with dvd/disc image. Should I try usb?